# How to adapt my versioning to Readme Driven Development?

Tags: npm, versioning, semantic-versioning, readme

I would like to conciliate RDD and Breaking.Feature.Fix versioning.

Here's my main issue, I am going to publish my README on NPM and I have no idea of **how to version software without actual code**. The README will go through many changes, it will have to be reflected by the version somehow.

Here are the problems I am facing:

- Would a breaking change in the API documented in the README be considered a major? Remember there's no code at that point.
- What should be the version of the first README commit? What's the convention?
- Which part (Major, Minor or Patch) should I bump on the first code commit? Again, I only had a README until then.
- Before the first code commit, should I use [prerelease tags](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#prerelease-tags) for my README versions?

Comment: To the one trying to close this: read the fourth point of https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: How do you even have an API "without actual code" ?!

Comment: @MSalters You should read about [RDD](http://tom.preston-werner.com/2010/08/23/readme-driven-development.html); imagine writing the final documentation before coding anything.

Comment: Are you compelled to use RDD?  If not, maybe all these concerns are telling you something…

Comment: @JohnHascall I am just asking about conventions and requesting advices. I could come up with something on my own if I didn't care. But versioning is mostly about the users' concerns not mine.

Comment: @david-brossard I am asking a question that could have answers based on conventions. This is "**a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development**". If I get opinions as answers that's probably because I put a bounty and few ppl know about RDD. There are ppl out there that have published RDD projects on NPM before.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I do it (EDITED):

I do not version documentation (including RDD) separately from the implementing code. I always start my software at 1.0.0, and typically start with an RDD document which may or may not have accompanying code, depending upon implementation complexity.

I do not start bumping the version number at all until there is code. This approach may not work if your RDD is a specification and there are other people implementing from your documentation. In which case, you may consider putting the documentation in its own repository and maintaining its own version history, which is separate from the version history of implementing software. If you maintain them separately, your RDD version rules should follow the same principles as software version rules. Breaking.Feature.Fix.

Otherwise, if you don't intend to maintain separate versioning for your RDD, before any code exists, I think it's usually fine to start at 1.0.0, and not increment it at all until you start pushing implementing code. I would put any unimplemented docs in a `docs/RDD` folder, or similar, to distinguish it from the documentation for code that has been implemented.

My original answers applied to CODE versions, not documentation versions:

- *"Would a breaking change in the API—documented in the README—be considered a major?"* -- Yes, absolutely.
- *"What should be my very first version?"* -- Start at 1.0.0. Version numbers are for software, not people. Every breaking change should be communicated with a change to the major version number.
- *"Which part should I bump on the first code commit?"* -- Your first code commit should be @1.0.0.
- *"Should I use prerelease tags?"* -- You should tag your recommended stable version as **latest**. Do use prerelease tags if you have an experimental release candidate that needs broader testing but is not ready for general production use.

You can read more about my software version recommendations in ["Software Versions are Broken"](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/software-versions-are-broken-3d2dc0da0783).

Comment: You are saying my very first version and my first code commit should both be @ 1.0.0; unless you don't know about RDD that doesn't make any sense in my case. In short you are not addressing the problem arising from RDD.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not compelled to use 'true' RDD, and since one of the main premises of RDD is that it is DDD for people who think DDD is too heavy weight, I would say take what you like from RDD ( and I like the idea ) and use it and don't worry if you are "doing RDD right".

As to your specific questions:

Yes, I would say a non-backwards compatible API change is definitely a major version bump ( at least once you get to V1 ).

I'm modest, I tend to start everything at 0.0.0. -- if you think your first effort is general release quality, hey, go with 1.0.0 !

Depends on the amount of change.

I don't -- if you find value, I would.